# jQuery - Another way to write this statement (DRY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry, prop

I am wondering if there's a way to write the following code without the if / else.

Currently, this works fine. But I'm trying to figure out how I can leverage a DRY method and I don't like the fact that the prop is written twice.

I have a text value and the user needs to input that code into the text box. Once the values match, it "enables" the submit button, otherwise it disables it.

```
$( '#input-code' ).on( 'change keyup paste', function() {
  if ( $( this ).val() == $( "#random-code" ).text() ) {
    $( '#submit-btn' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
  } else {
    $( '#submit-btn' ).prop( 'disabled', true );
  }
});
```

Comment: Set a val to `!=` the condition and use that as the prop value. IMO the inline ternaries suggested are harder to reason about. If you go the online route, personally I'd find using `!==` easier to read than backtracking to find out the whole expression is inverted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can migrate the `if..else` into a internal condition to set the attribute,

```
$( '#input-code' ).on( 'change keyup paste', function() {
    $( '#submit-btn' ).prop( 'disabled', this.value !== $( "#random-code" ).text() );
});
```

Additionally, if you are dealing with modern browsers, you can just use `on('input'` instead of `'change keyup paste'`. Check for browser support though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the negated expression directly in `prop`.

This will `disable` the button when button text and the `text` inside `#random-code` will be same.

Make sure you `trim` the `text()`, to remove leading and trailing spaces, otherwise it will not match with the button text.

```
$('#input-code').on('change keyup paste', function() {
    $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', !($(this).val() == $.trim($("#random-code").text())));
});
```

OR

```
$('#input-code').on('change keyup paste', function() {
    $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', $(this).val() !== $.trim($("#random-code").text()));
    //                                              ^^^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input-code').on('change keyup paste', function() {
    $('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', function(){
            return ( $( this ).val() == $( "#random-code" ).text() );
    });
});
```

for more detail you can check here...
[Jquery prop() detail.....](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)